# Laravel create users and automaticly add something in other database

Tags: php, database, laravel

We have been trying to add user roles to laravel but we got stuck on adding a role automaticly to a other database table.

We would like to add the User id and role id to this database with a default value,  when a user creates a new account:
[image]

We have no idea where to look for this since we are new to Laravel

Comment: Can you post some code for the sign up process, we cannot see what you are trying to do from that picture

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways to do this.

The easiest way is setting the column of your table to the desired default value. However this would be a bad idea since your column is a foreign key.

Another solution would be attaching a role when your user has been created. This can be accomplished with [events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#events).

An example would be:

```
// App\Provider\AppserviceProvider

public function boot()
{
    // EDIT!!! @ivanka-todorova comment
    // Changed creating to created
    User::created(function ($user) {

        $user->role()->attach('desired role id');

    });

}
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: I think it should be on `User::created`, because the `User` model should be saved in DB in order Laravel to get the id and attach it. But I'm not quite sure.

Comment: Hi I've still not figured it out yet... Could you help me with it in private chat?  Would be amazing

Comment: I would love to help. How can we have a private chat? @ThomH